# Is a function $f:\mathbb{Z}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}$ injective?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

The elements of $\mathbb{Z}^2$ would all be positive perfect squares, so when mapped onto integers, it is injective right?

Comment: $1 \mapsto 1, 4 \mapsto 1, 9 \mapsto 1, 16 \mapsto 1, \dots$

Comment: how can 4 map to 1?

Comment: $Z^2$ usually means the set of ordered pairs of integers, not the set of squares.

Comment: @baba Why not? I just thought of the first function that comes to mind, which is constant.

Comment: so all functions from Z^2 to Z are therefore NOT injective?

Comment: Some are, some aren't.

Comment: I do not understand the question as it is stated.. are you asking "does there exists " a function $f : \mathbb{Z}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$ which is injective which is not constant function??

Comment: In the first comment, @user61527 shows a counterexample (assuming that what you meant to ask was "are **all** functions ... injective?").

Comment: yes, I was wondering if **all** functions were injective for the given mapping. Thank you for the responses

Comment: A function *is* a mapping. It does not make any sense to ask "all functions are injective for a given mapping".

Comment: I meant for the given domain and codomain. Sorry

Answer (score 2):

Usually $Z^2$ denotes the cartesian product of the integers with the integers. For a proof there is a bijection between them see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/12167/the-set-of-rationals-has-the-same-cardinality-as-the-set-of-integers).

---

We now discuss the case if $Z^2 $ denotes the set of perfect squares:

The function that sends every integer $k$ to $k^2$ is not injective, since $1^2=(-1)^2$. If you restrict it to non-negative elements then that function is indeed an injection.

There is a bijection between them though, just map the positive integers to the even squares and the negative integers to the odd squares. So $f(0)=0$ and $f(n)=(2n)^2$ if $n$ is positive and $f(n)=(-2n-1)^2$ if $n$ is negative.