# List of explicit enumerations of rational numbers

Tags: set-theory, cardinals, big-list

A well-known mathematical fact is that the rational numbers are countable, i.e. there is a bijective function

$$f:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow \mathbb{Q}$$

I am interesting in making a list of all explicit such bijections since each one that I know have a different philosophy behind it.

This is one of the more counterintuitive facts about infinite, at least when one enters inside set theory. When I explain this in the first time to anyone, he/she is surprised. Thus I think  it will be useful for showing the fact in a more clear manner or as possible exercises to show alternatives ways with respect to the standard one.

Comment: This is community wiki.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Produce an explicit bijection between rationals and naturals?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/7643/produce-an-explicit-bijection-between-rationals-and-naturals)

Comment: This is not a duplicate, as he is asking a list of all such bijections.

Comment: Your list will have ${\aleph_{0}}^{\aleph_{0}}$ items.

Comment: I doubt that you will get any sensible answer. Note that it is sufficient to find 'explicit' bijections from $g:\mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$, and just apply $f g $ for a fixed $f$. This might be more intuitive to you, though it hides what happens in $fg$.

Comment: Such a "list" would have uncountably many entries IF one includes only one bijection in each item on the list.  But maybe there are some interesting ways of classifying the various sorts of bijections between these two sets.

Comment: I hope to see if there are different approaches distinct from the usual ones, in this way obtaining essentially different ideas for such a bijection.

Answer (score 8):

For an example I like a lot the following one based on the fundamental theorem of arithmetic, which is different from the usual approach using the plane.

Consider the map $T:\mathbb{N}\mapsto \mathbb{Z}$ given by
$$T(n)=(-1)^n\left\lfloor \frac{n+1}{2}\right\rfloor$$
which is a bijection from $\mathbb{N}=\{0,1,\ldots\}$ onto $\mathbb{Z}$. Then the fundamental theorem of arithmetic gives the following nice bijection $R:\mathbb{N}_1\rightarrow \mathbb{Q}_{>0}$ given by
$$R(n)=\prod_{p\text{ prime}}p^{T(\nu_p(n))}\text{,}$$
where $\nu_p$ is the $p$-adic valuation.

Joining this two we can have the desired bijection $f:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow \mathbb{Q}$ given by
$$f(n)=\begin{cases}
0 &\text{if }n=0\\
(-1)^nR(|T(n)|)&\text{if }n\neq 0\\
\end{cases}$$
which can be written as an explicit formula, but gives no new information.

Comment: This and other kind of constructions I am looking for.