# How to find how many irrational numbers are between $1$and $2$?

Tags: real-analysis

I know that the  open interval $(1,2)$ is uncountable. So there are an infinite amount of real numbers in the interval. Does there exist a ratio of rational numbers to irrational numbers?

Comment: The set of rational numbers is countable.

Comment: There are as many irrationals as real numbers in any interval. The Lebesgue measure of the set of irrational numbers in $(a,b)$ is $b-a$.

Comment: Yes, the ratio is $0$.

Comment: Put simply, the ratio of a countable set and an uncountable set would be 0 right? Since the uncountable set is infinite? Sort of like dividing by n as n goes to infinity?

Answer (score 3):

We can put the set of rational numbers and natural numbers in one-to-one correspondence, and hence show that the number of natural numbers is equal to the number of rational numbers.

Hence, we have $\mathbb{R}$ (Real numbers) an uncountable infinity.

$\mathbb{Q}$ (Rational numbers) a countable infinity, and, $\mathbb{R}-\mathbb{Q}$ (Irrational numbers) an uncountable infinity.

Hence, the number of irrational numbers is strictly greater than irrational numbers.

Hence, the ratio of rational and irrational numbers is $0$.

Comment: Makes a lot sense! Thank you!

Comment: Welcome @Garrett, glad to help! :)

Answer (score 1):

The function

$$f(x):=\frac1{x-1},\quad x\in(1,2)$$

is a bijection from $(1,2)$ to $(1,\infty)$ with the property that map rational numbers to rational numbers and irrational numbers to irrational numbers.

If you knows that $(1,\infty)$ have the same number of rational and irrational than $\Bbb R$ you are done.

Answer (score 1):

The ratio is zero, the set of rationals is denumerable (countable) where as irrationals are uncountable. For a proof of cardinality of $\mathbb Q$ see [Produce an explicit bijection between rationals and naturals?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/7643/produce-an-explicit-bijection-between-rationals-and-naturals). Then note that $((1,2)\cap\mathbb Q)\cup((1,2)\cap(\mathbb R - \mathbb Q))=(1,2)$ where $\mathbb R - \mathbb Q$ denotes the irrationals. Since $(1,2)\cap\mathbb Q$ is countable and $(1,2)$ is uncountable it must be the case that $(1,2)\cap(\mathbb R - \mathbb Q)$ is uncountable as the finite union of countable sets is countable.

Answer (score 0):

In other words, you are asking what is the Lebesgue integral of the Dirichlet function (the characteristic function of the rationals):
$$
D(x) =1_{\mathbb Q}(x)=\left\{\begin{matrix} 
1 & \mbox{if } x\in\mathbb Q  \\ 
0 & \mbox{if } x \notin \mathbb Q \end{matrix}\right.
$$
Because the rationals are countable, the Lebesgue measure of the rational numbers is $0$. Therefore the Dirichlet function equals $0$ almost everywhere and the answer is $\int D(x)=0$.