# Unclear construction in a paper of Ornstein and Weiss

Tags: dynamical-systems, group-actions, ergodic-theory, entropy

I need help understanding the following construction (Taken from the paper "Entropy and isomorphism theorems for actions of amenable groups"):

> *Begin by taking the direct product of two dyadic odometers. The space for this
>    $\mathbb{Z^2}$-action can be thought of as the collection of all the different ways of organizing $\mathbb{Z^2}$, first into a tiling by
>
>    $2$ x $2$ squares, then a tiling by $4$ x $4$ squares, each well tiled by
>   the $2$ x $2$ squares, then a tiling by $8$ x $8$ squares, etc.  $\mathbb{Z^2}$ acts on this space of patterns
>   by translations. Next to each such pattern we will associate to each element of  $\mathbb{Z^2}$ a
>   random variable taking the values $+-$ with probability $(1/2,1/2)$. These random variables
>   will be independent, subject to the following constraints:*
>
> *$(1)$ in every $2$ x $2$ square the bottom pair is  equal  to the top pair;*
>
> *$(2)$ in every $4$ x $4$ square, the left pair of $2$ x $2$ squares equals the right pair of
>   $2$ x $2$ squares;*
>
> *$(3)$ in every $2^3$ x $2^3$ square the bottom pair of $2^2$ x $2^2$ squares equals the top pair of
>   $2^2$ x $2^2$ squares;*
>   .
>   .
>   .
>
> *$(2n)$  in every $2^{2n}$ x $2^{2n}$ square the left half of the square equals the the right
>   half of the square;*
>
> *$(2n+1)$ in every $2^{2n+1}$ x $2^{2n+1}$ square the bottom half of the square equals the top
>   half of the square.*
>   .
>   .
>   .
>
> *It is clear that along the $45^∘$ diagonals one sees independent random variables, thus
>   the entropy of  $ST$  is at least $\log 2$, while in the vertical and horizontal directions the
>   entropy is killed because we repeat exactly, infinitely many times. Thus  $h(S)=
> h(T)=0$ but  $h(ST)≥\log2$.*

I don't understand what exactly is the measure space in this construction. Is the underlying set a subset of $\mathrm{odometer}$ x $\mathrm{odometer}$ x $\{+,-\}^{\mathbb{Z^2}}$$?$ What is the measure?
Can someone help me figure it out? it's probably standard.
Thanks.

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hZLCJ.png) is a picture of the construction, if you prefer.

Comment: The description is somewhat confusing if you've never seen it before. The underlying set is indeed a subset of $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2 \times \{\pm\}^{\mathbb{Z}^2}$. As for the measure: it is Haar $\otimes$ Haar on the first two factors, and the text describes the conditional measures on the third factor. I'll have more time to describe it this evening.

Comment: @D.Thomine: Thanks, looking forward to read it.

Answer (score 3):

**Odometers**

Up to some variations, an odometer is the topological dynamical system whose state space is $\mathbb{Z}_2$, the set of [$2$-adic integers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-adic_number), and transformation is $T(x) = x+1$.

If you have never seen this before: $\mathbb{Z}_2$ is the completion of $\mathbb{Z}$ for the distance $d(x,y) = 2^{-\max \{n: 2^n | x \wedge 2^n | y\}}$. It is a compact topological group.

In practice, you can see an element of $\mathbb{Z}_2$ as a non-terminating (on the left) binary number $\ldots 010011$, where two numbers are added in the usual way (with carry to the left). For instance, $\ldots 010011+1 = \ldots 010100$. Topologically, it is homeomorphic to $\{0,1\}^\mathbb{N}$. Sometimes you may also see them represented by binary decimal numbers, such as $0.110010 \ldots$, but with carry to the right. For instance, $0.110010 \ldots+0.1 = 0.001010 \ldots$.

As a compact topological group, $\mathbb{Z}_2$ admits a unique translation-invariant probability measure, its [Haar measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haar_measure) $\mu_H$. Its distribution is the same as choosing all binary digits independently, $0$ or $1$ with probability $1/2$.

It turns out that $(\mathbb{Z}_2, T)$ is uniquely ergodic, its unique invariant probability measure being the Haar measure.

**Tilings**

What does this has to do with tilings? Well, let's consider tilings on $\mathbb{Z}$. There are only two tilings of $\mathbb{Z}$ with tiles of length $2$: the one with endpoints on even integers, and the one with endpoints on odd integers.

There are four tilings of $\mathbb{Z}$ with tiles of length $4$. However, if we are given a tiling by tiles of length $2$, only two of them are compatible. For instance, if we are given the even tiling of length $2$, then the compatible tilings of length $4$ are those whose endpoints are $0[4]$, or those whose endpoints are $2[4]$.

It's the same with tilings of length $8$: there are eight of them, but only two of them are compatible with any tiling of length $4$.

Let $X$ be the set of sequences of tilings $(T_2, T_4, T_8, \ldots)$, where $T_{2^n}$ is a tiling by tiles of length $2^n$, and they are all compatible. Then, when refining the tiling, we have two choices at each step, so this set can be easily made in bijection with $\{0,1\}^{\mathbb{N}}$.

For a specific bijection, for $n \geq 1$, let $u_n$ be the smallest nonnegative value of an endpoint of a tile of length $2^n$, put $u_0 := 0$, and let:

$$x_n = \left\{ \begin{array}{lll} 1 & \text{ if } & u_n = u_{n-1} \\ 0 & \text{ if } & u_n > u_{n-1} \end{array}\right.,$$

Then take $x := \ldots x_3 x_2 x_1 \in \mathbb{Z}_2$. For instance, $x = \ldots 010$ means that the $2$-tiles end on odd values, the $4$-tiles on $1[4]$ values, and the $8$-tiles on $5[8]$ values.

This yields a bijection $\varphi : X \to \mathbb{Z}_2$. The nice thing is that its conjugates the translation by $+1$ on $\mathbb{Z}$ (or rather, the translation $\widetilde{T}$ of $-1$ of the tilings) with $T$:

$$\varphi \circ \widetilde{T} = T \circ \varphi.$$

This gives you a geometric interpretation of the odometer as sequences of tilings. As a corollary, $X$ carries a unique translation-invariant probability measure.

Here is an example of tiling, its coding and the effect of the shift:

[image: Odometers, tilings and codings]

**The construction**

Now, $\mathbb{Z}^2$ acts on $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$ by direct product: $(n,m) \cdot (x,y) = (T^n (x), T^m (y))$. But $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$ can be seen as tilings of $\mathbb{Z}^2$ by squares (or rather, as compatible sequences of tilings by squares of side $2^n$); then $\mathbb{Z}^2$ acts merely by translation.

The set they construct is $\Omega \subset \mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2 \times \{\pm 1\}^{\mathbb{Z}^2} \simeq X \times X \times \{\pm 1\}^{\mathbb{Z}^2}$, corresponding to markings compatible with both tilings (i.e. triples $(x,y,z) \in X^2 \times \{\pm 1\}^{\mathbb{Z}^2}$ where $z$ satisfies a condition based on $x$ and $y$).

As for the measure: the only $\mathbb{Z}^2$-invariant measure on $X^2$ is $\varphi^* \mu_H \otimes \varphi^*\mu_H$. Then, given $(x,y) \in X^2$, the authors describe a measure on the set of good markings
$C(x,y) \subset \{ \pm 1 \}^{\mathbb{Z}^2}$. This is the distribution $\nu_{x,y}$ of $z$ conditionally to $(x,y)$. The total measure is (abusing notation and writing $\mu_H$ for $\varphi^* \mu_H$):

$$\mu := \iint \delta_x \otimes \delta_y \otimes \nu_{x,y} \ d \mu_H (x) \ d \mu_H (y).$$

Let us look closer at this step. Fix $x$ and $y$, that is, fix a sequences of tilings of $\mathbb{Z}^2$. Let $\sim$ be the equivalence relation on $\mathbb{Z}^2$ generated by the tiling and the prescribed rule. That is, if $\{(a,b), (a+1, b), (a, b+1), (a+1,b+1)\}$ is a $2\times 2$ tile, then $(a,b) \sim (a, b+1)$ and $(a+1,b) \sim (a+1, b+1)$, etc.

Then we have countably any equivalence classes $(\alpha_n)_{n \geq 0}$ on $\mathbb{Z}^2$. Let $(X_n)_{n \geq 0}$ be i.i.d., with value $\pm 1$ with probability $1/2$. Finally, let $Y (a,b) := X_n$ whenever $(a,b) \in \alpha_n$. Then, by construction, $(Y(a,b))_{(a,b) \in \mathbb{Z}^2} \in C(x,y)$, and $\nu_{x,y}$ is its distribution.

The statement that "one sees independent random variables along the $45°$ diagonal" comes from the fact that, on any $45°$ diagonal, all the cells belong to different equivalence classes, so the corresponding $Y(a,b)$ are independent.

Comment: Wow! thank you for this comprehensive answer. This actually how I tried to construct the measure space (a little bit after posting this question). My main problem was defining $\nu_{x,y}$, so I wasnt sure I'm in the right direction.  Can you please describe it?                 Thanks again anyway.

Comment: @Alfred: I've added a couple of paragraphs.

Comment: What is $C(x,y)$? and in line 6 (from the end ("Then we..")) do you give an example of some sort or define $\nu_{x,y}$? sorry for this simple questions. Im not very familiar with definitions from probability. (but am rather familiar with measure theory (set theoretical and topolgical measure Haar measure Riesz rep. thm. etc)).

Comment: @Alfred: $C(x,y) \subset \{\pm 1\}^{\mathbb{Z}^2}$ is defined two paragraphs above: it's the set of possible markings, given the tilings $(x,y)$. The second two last paragraph is a definition of $\nu_{x,y}$; I've tried to make the statement in the article ("independent, subject to the following constraints [...]") more explicit. The construction in my answer gives you a way to sample an element of $C(x,y)$, which is the same as sampling with $\nu_{x,y}$.