# Would my proof that $ \mathbb{Q} \sim\mathbb{N} $ count?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, functions, solution-verification

So I saw that $ \mathbb{Q}\sim\mathbb{N} $ and I tried to prove it.

The official proof was a function using prime factors.

I'm learning and in doing so I try to prove each theorem and corollary or example before I read the one in the script or book.
But mine was a little funky as I tried long and hard to think of something, but unfortunately couldn't come up with anything better.

Would this work:

Every number in $ \mathbb{Q}$ can be interpreted as two integers $a$ and $b$.
Then we can devise a function $f: \mathbb{Q} \rightarrow \mathbb{N} $ where $a$ is the first digit and $b$ is appended.

For example $f(5/4) = 54$ or $f(1/1) = 11$.

Is such a function even allowed?
Would it be injective and bijective?

Also, if this is an allowed function. Would $0/4$ and $0/1$ count as two different rational numbers or the same? ( I was struggling finding a definition for the zero numbers if they count as different).

Sorry if this is complete nonsense!

Comment: $\frac{11}1$, $\frac{1}{11}$.

Comment: $1/1=2/2$ but $f(1/1)=11$ and $f(2/2)=22$ so this isn't even a function, however you could define it that $a, b$ have to be coprime that would solve the issue and say that $f(0)=0$ and ignore the case $0/b$

Comment: This is neither injective not surjective, assuming you fix it as kingW3 suggests. Then 22 is not in the image, and f(54/11)=f(541/1)=5411$.

Comment: Finding a bijection is indeed hard as none of a+b, ab, a/b, a^n, are bijective, I think you can't make a bijective function with elementary operations but thinking instead of numbering rational numbers might be easier to think about.

Comment: thank you all, you quickly came up with so many examples, I feel silly that I tried many myself and couldn't find similar ones! thanks again!

Comment: Use `$\sim$` for $\sim$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you probably know by now, your $f$ is not injective (if it were a function), but most importantly, it is actually not a function as it is not well defined.

That is, as you pointed out, $0=\frac{0}{1}=\frac{0}{4}=\frac{0}{n}$. Thus, $f(0)$ could actually be any integer, so $f$ is not even a function.

If you want a explicit bijection you can have a look [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/7643/624325). It shows a bijection from rationals to naturals, but it is easy to modify it to get integers of course.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time and the link, I'll check it out, it's a different proof from the one in my book, but it uses one I've used before (Z to N). That's super cool!

Answer (score 3):

I like *Cantor's pairing function*.  You can look it up and get a formula.  But it is utterly trivial from a geometric point of view.   Roughly speaking,  arrange the rationals in an array, and then just zig-zag your way from the upper left hand corner to put them in a list.

Comment: Thanks, I've seen this a few chapters ago, I'll put it on my list to review. Awesome!

Answer (score 1):

Here is another route.  It is quite common when trying to prove that two sets $A$ and $B$ have the same cardinality that you can fairly easily find a function $f:A \rightarrow B$ which is an injection but not a surjection and another $g:B \rightarrow A$ which is also an injection but not a surjection.

Intuitively, this says that $|A| \le |B|$ and $|B| \le |A|$ so $|A| = |B|$.

The [Schröder–Bernstein theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6der%E2%80%93Bernstein_theorem) deals with this case: you can deduce that the sets have the same cardinality.  It is worth studying that and then you can stop once you find such a pair of injections.

Even in a fairly simple case such as yours, an explicit bijection can be rather messy.

Comment: Thank you, in my script this was mentioned but reduced to a simple line and not further commented. I seen it more detailed in How to prove it's new edition. I will check it out. Most proofs I've seen only show an injection and not a surjection.