# Given a field $k$, show that an injection $\mathbb{Z} \rightarrow k$ implies an injection $\mathbb{Q} \rightarrow k$

Tags: abstract-algebra, functions, elementary-set-theory

I am trying to prove that the existence of an injection $\mathbb{Z} \rightarrow k$ implies the existence of an injection $\mathbb{Q} \rightarrow k$, where $k$ is a field.

I started by defining an equivalence relation $\sim$ on $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}_+$ such that $(a, b) \sim (c, d) \iff ad = bc$. Then I have a bijection from the set of equivalence classes of $\sim$ to $\mathbb{Q}$, i.e $f : [\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}_+]_\sim{} \rightarrow \mathbb{Q}$.

This is where I get stuck: if $g : \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Q}$ is the injection, I tried to construct injection $h : [\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}_+]_\sim{} \rightarrow k$ from $g$. The only thing I could think of was $h([(a, b)]) = g(a)g(b)^{-1}$, but I can't prove that $g(b) \ne 0$ or that $h$ is an injection without assuming $g$ is a ring homomorphism. If $h$ is an injection, then I have the injection $h \circ f^{-1} : \mathbb{Q} \rightarrow k$.

Am I approaching this the right way? Is this provable at all?

EDIT: For context, this is question was asked in an abstract algebra class, but the question did not explicitly state that the function $\mathbb{Z} \rightarrow k$ is a ring homomorphism. To answer it as posed, I would have to construct a bijection from $\mathbb{Q} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$. This question has been answered [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/7643/produce-an-explicit-bijection-between-rationals-and-naturals).

Comment: Given that it's an abstract algebra class, perhaps the intent of the question is that if $\mathbb{Z}\to k$ is an injective ring map, then $k$ contains an isomorphic copy of $\mathbb{Z}$, hence must contain the quotient field $\operatorname{Quot}(\mathbb{Z})\simeq\mathbb{Q}$ as a subfield, which is to say there is an injective field map $\mathbb{Q}\to k$. This actually makes use of the hypothesis that $k$ is a field.

Comment: For what it's worth, this is an immediate result of the universal property of localization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wonder if the question is correctly stated and correctly tagged.

The tags `abstract-algebra`, `ring-theory` and `field-theory` seem to imply that you are talking about **injective ring homomorphisms** rather than just injections. In this case, your approach is correct (but perhaps a bit overcomplicated).

However you explicitly stated "without assuming $g$ is a ring homomorphism". If this means that you are talking about set-theoretic injections, then the answer is to note that there is a bijection between $\Bbb Q$ and $\Bbb Z$. This would be more suitable as an exercise in set theory.

Comment: Apologies -- I am new to this forum. The question I was trying to answer did not explicitly state that the function $\mathbb{Z} \rightarrow k$ is a ring homomorphism, so I interpreted it as a set-theoretic injection. I will re-tag the question.

Comment: It then depends on the context. If the question comes from algebra context such as ring theory or field theory, then it probably wants to say that $g$ is a ring homomorphism, which makes it a quite standard exercise. Sometimes people simply say "injections" when they mean "injective homomorphisms".

Comment: Thanks for the response, I just updated the question -- it probably meant 'ring homomorphism'

Answer (score 1):

There are two different interpretations of injections here.

1. $\mathbb{Z}\to k$ is an injective ring homomorphism.  Then your $\mathbb{Q}\to k$ is an injective ring (or field) homomorphism.
2. $\mathbb{Z}\to k$ is an injection of underlying sets.  Then you get $\mathbb{Q}\to k$ an injection of underlying sets by composing with an injection $\mathbb{Q}\to\mathbb{N}\hookrightarrow\mathbb{Z}$ (since $\mathbb{Q}$ is countable).