# Bijection $\mathbb N \to \mathbb Z$ using floor function. Define bijection $\mathbb Z \to \mathbb Q$

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

After defining the bijection
$$ 
F: \mathbb{N}\to \mathbb{Z}$$ using floor function,
and by defining bijections:

$$\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N} \setminus \{ 0 \}\\
\mathbb{Q} \to \mathbb{Q} \setminus \{ 0 \} 
$$

define bijection:

$$\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Q} \setminus \{ 0 \}$$.

After a few attempts I got first one $F: \Bbb N \to \Bbb Z$ , $F(x) = (-1)^x \lfloor(x/2)\rfloor$ but I'm stuck with other ones.
I'm new into that course at university - if I made some mistakes - I'm sorry.

Comment: $\mathbb N\to\mathbb N\setminus\{0\}:x\mapsto x+1$ is a bijection. Also, doesn't $F$ send $0$ and $1$ both to $0$?

Comment: Forget solving the first three for the time being.  Let's supposed you paid some one and they came up with bijections $F:N\to Z$ and $G:N \to N\setminus \{0\}$ and $H:Q\to Q\setminus \{0\}$.  And you were left to fine a bijection $J:Z\to Q\setminus\{0\}$... could you?

Answer (score 1):

1. $F : \mathbb N \to \mathbb Z$ defined as $F(n)=(-1)^n \lfloor {n+1 \over 2} \rfloor$.
2. $G : \mathbb N \to \mathbb N \backslash \{0\}$ defined as $G(n)=n+1$.
3. $H : \mathbb Q \to \mathbb Q \backslash \{0\}$ defined as $H(n)=n+1$ for $n \in \mathbb N$ and identity function otherwise.
4. You can find very nice detailed answers [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/7643/produce-an-explicit-bijection-between-rationals-and-naturals).